# VS 2015 CTP 6 + Cordova + Windows 10 Technical Preview for Phones

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-win10

Is it possible to debug Cordova App using Windows 10 Technical preview for phones device?  I have a Lumia 635 with Windows 10 preview installed.  Using Blank Cordova app for testing.

I get a DEP1700 error.

[image: windows phone 10]

Comment: It looks like the build failed (which is why it didn't generate a recipe file) but it wasn't detected as a failure so it went ahead and tried to deploy.  The issue is most likely unrelated to the fact that the device is running Windows 10 Technical Preview for Phones.  Not having the Windows Development tools installed might cause this symptom.  You could check that you have these options installed.  Setting your build output to Diagnostic and rebuilding might reveal what's interrupting the build.  Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run

Comment: Ellen,  thanks for the help. It helped me find the following:  `Error: Failed to connect to device as it is developer locked. For details on 

developer unlock, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195284.`

Answer (score 2):

Using Ellen's solution, Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions>Build and Run > Change verbosity to "Diagnostic", I was able to get the following error:

`Severity   Code Description Project    File Line
Error Error: Failed to connect to device as it is developer locked. For details on developer unlock, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195284.`

Solve this problem by registering the phone with Windows Phone Developer Registration on the desktop.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, I had to restart visual studio after registering phone.  Also, if you are using a shared project make sure you are deploying to phone and not just deploy as this will likely default to the desktop app.